# Button click doesn't trigger in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, click

**Problem** : I have a button and its "click" event only triggers 1 time out of 2 or 3 in Safari. In every other browser, its "click" event is triggered everytime the button is clicked.

Here's my code :

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 alert("Clicked");
});
```

```css
button{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background: #ea5949;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #a03d32;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px 3px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button:hover{
  top: -2px;
  animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #a03d32;
}

button:active{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444;
    top: 4px;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click on me</button>
```

is that Safari doesn't like the "top" value changing during the button's "active" state (code below), perhaps affecting the hitbox. Does that make sense? I could be completely wrong though.

```
button:active{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444;
    top: 4px;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}
```

I've tried using the "transform" CSS property instead, but the issue persists.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` of the click event must occur on the button itself. You can recreate this behaviour by clicking (and holding) on the top of the button. It then moves down below the cursor. If you now release the click nothing happens, as the `mouseup` was fired on the `body`, not the `button`. There's no workaround for this on the `button` element directly - it's just how the DOM's JS event model works. An alternative would be to wrap the `button` in another `div` and attach the `click` event to that - although it would be rather hacky.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Safari on OS X El Capitan.